# Some bindings no longer work after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: i3

It seems some binding no longer work, in particular $mod+q and $mod+v.

```
bindsym --release $mod+q kill
bindsym $mod+v split v
```

Other bindings still work fine. Any ideas?

Ubuntu has switched from Unity to Gnome as the Desktop not sure if this is a factor.

- i3 4.14.1
- ubuntu 18.0.4 upgraded from 16.04 (xenial) LTS.
- full config: https://github.com/krisleech/ansible-desktop/blob/master/templates/i3_config

Comment: For `$mod+q` it seems I have to hold the key combination down for longer.

Comment: To fix `mod+q` I had to remove `--release` from the key binding. However `mod+v` still fails to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare bindsym $mod+v twice in your config.

Once here: `bindsym --release $mod+v exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v`

and again here:`bindsym $mod+v split v`

`bindsym` only listens to the first of duplicate declarations after some testing (ie: xdotool). Change the key to get results

Comment: Thanks so much. I wonder why it worked before, maybe I had a different version of i3... Nevermind :)